# Why in this login page backend server accept all the password if I give wrong password then it also accept

Tags: javascript, mongodb, authentication, jwt, backend

I put the wrong password but it gets login successfully and the data which is inside a particular user is as a new user login. I want you to please tell me a error.

Link of an online hosted project: [NOTEBOOK/login](https://mern-notebook.onrender.com/)

Link of GitHub repository: [GITHUB/notebook](https://github.com/Rajat2024/NoteBook)

The login folder is inside `routes/auth.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/User')
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
let fetchuser = require('../middleware/fetchuser')
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const secret=process.env.YOUR_SECRET

router.post('/login', [
    body('email', 'Enter a valid Email').isEmail(),
    body('password', 'Password cannot be blank').exists()
], async (req, res) => {
    let success=false;
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    try {
        // check whether user with this email  exist
        let user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({success, error: "Please login using correct credentials" })
        };
        let passwordCompare = bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!passwordCompare) {
            return res.status(400).json({success, error: "Please login using correct credentials" })
        };
        const data = {
            user: {
                id: user.id
            }
        }
        var authtoken = jwt.sign(data, secret);
        success=true;
        res.json({success, authtoken })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        res.status(500).send("Internal server error has occured")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to wait for the promise to resolve, you can opt for any of the below options

1. const passwordCompare = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

OR

2. const passwordCompare = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);

OR

3. bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(function(result) {
   // result == true
   });